# Can I access a specific view from a WKWebView using a Segue?

Tags: ios, swift, segue, wkwebview

I have a simple app that uses a WKWebView to show a website.

The purpose of the app is to memorize the users credentials inside a SQLite database and avoid having to log in each time he browses the website on his phone. (bad credentials are not yet handled)

This is handled in the AppDelegate who checks if the database has any user entries ;

- if it does the app loads the webView
- if not, a login view is displayed

Whenever the user logs out of the website within the webview, the app deletes the user in the SQLite database which forces him to access the login view next time he launches the app.

The problem is, when the user logs out of the website within the webview I can't seem to navigate to another view.

I've tried linking a segue to the login view but I can't seem to link a webview to another view.

Basically, how can I do a **WKWebView ----> Login View Controller** segue relationship ?

Comment: Fwiw, that second paragraph is terrifying. Apple created Keychain APIs for exactly this purpose. You should never be storing user credentials in a SQLite db.

Comment: Duly noted, I will make the change shortly after this problem is resolved.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to grab the Login View Controller from the storyboard.

**Solution 1**

```
let mainStoryboard: UIStoryboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)

var loginViewController = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"LoginViewController"];
// segue to the loginViewControll however you want.
```

**Solution 2**

Make a segue from storyboard between the View Controller which holds the WKWebView and Login View Controller.
[image]
Then call perfromSegue in WebView View Controller

```
performSegue(withIdentifier "WebViewToLoginSegue", sender: self)
```

Comment: Thank you !
My problem was that I kept trying to link the WebView instead of the Controller, making the segue unable to appear.